# jmeter if procedure has no out variable how to use declared variable in other procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, jmeter

Have one **JDBC** request using callable type with following details:

```
declare
in_error_log varchar2(20);
begin
in_error_log := '112222bbbb';
end;
```

There is no in and out parameters.

I want to use variable in_error_log in other `JDBC request`, how can i pass it to other request?

I have tried regular expression, not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [User Defined Variables](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65146-using-user-defined-variables-in-jmeter-2-6) config element to hold your `in_error_log` value.

Please remember that JMeter Variables have Thread Group local scope, variable defined in one Thread Group cannot be used in another Thread Group. If it's your case - you'll need to convert JMeter Variable to JMeter Property i.e. by using [Beanshell Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor)

Sample Beanshell code to convert `in_error_log` variable to property with the same name will look like:

```
props.put("in_error_log", vars.get("in_error_log"));
```